# Can an LTC4372 ideal diode controller drive multiple parallel MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, ideal

I am designing an ideal diode circuit for back EMF protection and reverse polarity protection outputting on average 60 A from a 4s9p li-ion battery to run 8 motors.

For this circuit, I used an LTC4372 as an ideal diode controller to control 2 MOSFETs as following (ignoring 2UPU and SHDN pins I use for my purpose in other schematics):

[image]

Normally, I would have several of the above circuits in parallel for current sharing.

[image]

I am not too sure and a bit curious if multiple back-to-back MOSFETs can be connected in parallel like in the configuration below:

[image: Parallel MOSFETs]

Answer (score 1):

Multiple MOSFETs in parallel behave exactly like one large MOSFET due to the positive temperature coefficient of the on resistance (on resistance goes up with temperature, thereby ensuring proper current sharing).

As long as your controller can drive the combined gate charge of the parallel MOSFETs, this will work just fine.

You should not give each MOSFET its own gate resistor, though. Instead, parallel the MOSFETs directly (gate, source, and drain terminals directly connected) and only give the overall parallel MOSFETs a single gate resistor to ensure that the gate voltage of all of them is always equal.